# Установка модуля Modern::perl посредством CPAN

Tags: bash, perl

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться куда CPAN устанавливает модули, только начинаю изучать perl и плохо ориентируюсь в его использовании.
В частности, использование команды say вместо print требует использования модуля Moder::perl

допустим имеется файл:

```
~/perl$ cat ./34
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;


say "34";
```

Который дает следующий вывод:

```
$ ./34
Can't locate Modern/Perl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the    
 Modern::Perl module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl 
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22
 /usr/local/lib/site_perl 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .)     at ./34 line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./34 line 2.
```

С помощью CPAN был скачан соответствующий модуль. 
В целом модуль оказался скачанным после команды install Modern::Perl

Так как вывод оказался прежним, был использован следующий метод:

```
~/.cpan/build/Modern-Perl-1.20170117-ZIYFay$ perl Makefile.PL 
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Modern::Perl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

~/.cpan/build/Modern-Perl-1.20170117-ZIYFay$ make
Skip blib/lib/Modern/Perl.pm (unchanged)
Manifying 1 pod document

:~/.cpan/build/Modern-Perl-1.20170117-ZIYFay$ make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-            
MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0,         
'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/base.t .......... ok   
t/regressions.t ... ok    
t/unimport.t ...... ok   
t/year_imports.t .. ok    
All tests successful.
Files=4, Tests=88,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.01 sys +  0.15 cusr  0.03 csys =  0.22 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

После чего был вновь запущен тот же файл ./34:

```
~/perl$ ./34
Can't locate Modern/Perl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the    
Modern::Perl module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl 
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 
/usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22
/usr/local/lib/site_perl 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .)     at ./34 line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./34 line 2.
```

В результате был составлен следующий файл list, содержащий все пути из ошибки:

```
~/perl$ for i in `cat list`; do echo $i ; done
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1
/usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22
/usr/share/perl/5.22
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
```

По которому я пробежался командой find, с целью найти слово Modern в указанных путях, результат был слудеющим:

```
$ for i in `cat list`; do find $i  -name '*Modern*' ; done
find: «/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1»: Нет такого файла или каталога
find: «/usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1»: Нет такого файла или каталога
find: «/usr/local/lib/site_perl»: Нет такого файла или каталога


 При этом:
~/perl$ perl -wE 'say 34'
34
```

Суть вопроса, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться каким образом я могу начать использовать команды say и прочие из 5.10 версии в своих сценариях.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо ничего устанавливать. Say (и прочие) включается автоматически, если вы переключаетесь на Перл 5.10. Добавьте в скрипт "use v5.10;". Можно активировать эту фичу отдельно: "use feature 'say';".

Comment: Благодарю, use 5.010 действительно сработал, но вопрос с установкой модуля и принципа его подключения также интересен.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем лезть в дебри и ставить модуль ручками? Это всё уже автоматизировано.
Для этого нужно использовать комманду `cpan` или более современный вариант `cpanm`:

```
cpan Modern::Perl
```

Устанавливается модуль в систему и поэтому может потребовать sudo.

---

Для установки модуля в свои собственные папки нужно настроить переменные окружения:

```
export PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/home/$(whoami)/perl5\""
export PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/$(whoami)/perl5"
```

И для того, чтобы перл увидел (знал где искать ваши модули) нужно установить `PERL5LIB`:

```
export PERL5LIB='/home/$(whoami)/perl5/lib/perl5'
```

Эти комманды вы должны положить в ваш `~/.bash_aliases`

Но сейчас я делаю всё это через [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/). Это более современный способ.
Установить его можно так:

```
$ \wget -O - https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
```

И также для удобства добавляете в `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
if [ -f ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc ]; then
  source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
  source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/perlbrew-completion.bash
  alias pb="perlbrew"
  complete -F _perlbrew_compgen pb
fi
```

Далее смотрите какие `perl` доступны, выбираете:

```
$ perlbrew available
```

И ставите:

```
$ perlbrew install perl-5.26.1
```

не забудьте переключиться на него:

```
$ perlbrew switch perl-5.26.1
$ perl -v
```

---

Стоит упомянуть, что после инсталляции у вас в домашней директории появится папка `~/perl5`. Туда и будут ставится все новый модуля. Для установки модуля используете

```
$ cpan <Module::Name>
$ cpanm <Mоdule::Name>
```

Для последнего (более современного) не забудьте сделать его установку:

```
perlbrew install-cpanm
```

ЗЫ. Удачи при инсталляции модулей ;-)

Answer (score 0):

вы просто забыли после `make test` запустить `make install` ;-)
Поэтому модуль и не найден

Для установки модулей лучше использовать комманду:

```
cpan <Module::Name>
```